# mocking a require()'d imported object with jest/sinon

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, jestjs

here's my code:

```
const Config = require('Config');

export const getPayments = (username: string) => {

  if (username === undefined) {
    throw new Error('username is undefined');
  }

  const envEndpoint = Config.paymentsEndpoint;
  const endpoint: string = `${envEndpoint}/${username}`;

  return fetch(endpoint);
};
```

What I want to mock is the Config object. I basically want to intercept that require call in my test file and replace it with a an object with that paymentsEndpoint value. I am using jest, but also have sinon as an option for mocking.

I am still fairly new to unit tests and jest, so forgive me if I used incorrect terminology

Answer (score 2):

In your test file *before* you import your `getPayments` module, you can use `jest.mock` to mock the Config module.

So it would look something like

```
/* getPayments.test.js */

jest.mock('Config', () => {
  return { paymentsEndpoint: 'y' }; // return your fake Config obj here
});

import getPayments from './getPayments'; // or whatever the correct file path is

describe(() => {
  [ ... your tests ]
});
```

here are the `jest.mock` docs: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options

Comment: `const Config = require('Config');` is not needed in the test

Comment: I think that's a point in the right direction, but I am now getting this error:
    `Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'Config' from 'expertsApi.test.ts'
      
      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-
      resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/clients/expertsApi.test.ts:44:6)` Also, I am very sorry I forgot to mention this is typescript

Comment: That’s weird it looks like the mock might not be working. Is expertsApi.test.ts the file where you’ve defined the mock? And if so is the mock defined above the getPayments import?

Comment: okay so [this thread](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/120) says that default exports work differently in TS - in the mock callback instead of `return YourFakeConfigObj;` could you try `return { 'default': YourFakeConfigObj };`